# Apache 2.4 rewrite for /index/refresh gives 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

when I try to load up the site with /refresh, or /index or anything at all, it will call the `index.php` and route it correctly through the Zend Framework.

But once I try to load up /index/refresh (or anything with multiple directories), apache (2.4) pumps out a 404...
I assume this is because it's looking for the /index directory, and than something in there, but can't find this directory...

I did test this with Bolt's htaccess_tester.php to confirm my suspicions...

Is there anything wrong with this rewrite file that prevents it from working with multiple "directories"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, there was somewhere a MultiViews still active. Disabling all of them fixed my issue. Case closed.